# Eloquent: Find all records of a table base on a one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `grades` and `students`, each grade belongs to a student. and I want to find all grades based on **some students(not a student)** that have a common attribute, for example, Students that are a boy.

```
class Student extends Model
{    
public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Grade');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Grade extends Model
{
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
}
```

So, I try this code, but it's wrong because it works if we have a student, not some students:

```
$grades = Student::where('sex','male')->grades->latest('created_at')->paginate(20);
```

And I'm looking for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the relationship method can be called by one eloquent.

So you just want to get the grades' records of male students, you can just get them out from Grade.

```php
$grades = Grade::whereHas('student', function($q) { 
    return $q->where('sex', 'male');
})->latest('created_at')->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public function grades()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Grade','student_id','student_id');
}

$grades = Student::with('grades')->where('sex','male')->latest('created_at')->paginate(20);
```